# How can I center some text using bootstrap 4 in a full sized jumbotron and setting a max-width for just the div or p container?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, center, text-align

I'm learning how to use bootstrap 4 and when I try to horizontal center some text in a full sized jumbotron, it works just fine. When I try to put a max-width on that text container, it then puts all of the text onto the left hand side of the jumbotron.

Using the class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" makes it work. Once I add the style="max-width: 600px" it breaks it and puts the text to the far left.

Here is my current code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-4 text-sm-center">Main Header</h1>
    <div style="max-width: 600px" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <p class="lead">Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the text to have a max-width of 600px and be horizontally centered in the jumbotron.

Comment: Where is your code? Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mark the code as code and it removed all of the tags. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the CSS `margin: auto;` should do the trick for you. I added a snippet.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="jumbotron">

    <h1 class="display-4 text-sm-center">Main Header</h1>
    
    <div style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;" class="d-flex center justify-content-center align-items-center">
    
        <p class="lead">Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum 
            faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus. 
            Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus 
            dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus.</p>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

You should avoid inlining CSS, consider putting the CSS in a separate file and importing it.

Comment: Awesome! That did the job. Yes Rual, I put CSS in a separate but was easier to put it inline for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `<center style="">` your `<div></div>` and other codes `</center>`

Comment: I guess I was trying to overthink it. The <center> tag worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: The only problem I guess is that PHP Storm is telling me that the <center> tag is a depreciated HTML tag.

Comment: When I replace the <center> tag with "text-align: center" I get my original issue back. The text is moved to the left again.

Comment: Yeah. You cant use the align-center with <center>, it negates.